# How to split a Column of json Object to More Column via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

how can i split this json object to post to column in database name, hobby, age

```
{
"student1":"john smitch,reading,15",
"student2":"albert North, running,13"
}
```

My db Name: new, Table Name: registration, This is my php code:

```
 public function index_post()
{
        //$this->some_model->update_user( ... );
        $data = [
        'name' => $this->post('student1'),
   ];
            $message = ['registration was successful']
            $this->db->insert("registration", $data);
            $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // CREATED (201) being the HTTP response code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make the data an PHP array or object
- walk thru and trim the entries separated by comma
- insert row

```
$json = '{
    "student1":"john smitch,reading,15",
    "student2":"albert North, running,13"
}';

$sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO registration SET name=?, hobby=?, age=?');
foreach(json_decode($json) as $key => $value)
    $sth->execute(array_map(fn($e) => trim($e), explode(',', $value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first decode the JSON with

```
$students = json_decode($json);
```

then you can iterate through all students by

```
foreach($students as $key => $student)
```

now you can split this string with

```
$studentAtributes = explode(',', $student);
```

and then iterate over all attributes with

```
foreach($studentAtributes as $attribute)
```